# How does one use Swift protocol extensions to create shared code that can modify private properties?

Tags: swift, inheritance, protocols

Hypothetical scenario:

There are classes: `ClassA`; and `ClassB`. Both implement `ProtocolC`, which contains the single requirement `func createKey()`. `ProtocolC` has an `extension` that implements `createKey()` because in respect of this function, the functionality required by `ClassA` and `ClassB` is identical. However, the implementation of `createKey()` needs to access a private variable named `uniqueKey` that both `ClassA` and `ClassB` contain, the value of which needs to be different in the two classes (as you might imagine). The `extension` of `createKey()` in `ProtocolC` therefore becomes useless - because the variable are `fileprivate` - meaning its code has to be duplicated in both `ClassA` and `ClassB`. But duplicated code is a programming no-no. A solution *could be* to use a superclass rather than a protocol extension, but this cuts against the grain of what Swift is trying to achieve. Inheritance is a Swift no-no.

```
// the ideal:

class ClassA: ProtocolC {
    fileprivate var uniqueKey: String?
}

class ClassB: ProtocolC {
    fileprivate var uniqueKey: String?
}

protocol ProtocolC {
    func createKey()
}

extension ProtocolC {
    func createKey(){
        uniqueKey = NSUUID().uuidString
    }
}



// the reality:

class ClassA: ProtocolC {
    fileprivate var uniqueKey: String?
    func createKey(){
        uniqueKey = NSUUID().uuidString
    }
}

class ClassB: ProtocolC {
    fileprivate var uniqueKey: String?
    func createKey(){
        uniqueKey = NSUUID().uuidString
    }
}
```

`uniqueKey` needs to be locked inside the two classes, not settable nor gettable from without. What is the solution in Swift to writing: generic code that can access private properties; whilst avoiding inheritance?

Thank you for reading.

Comment: No suggestions thus far. Am I to give in and either: duplicate code; or use inheritance? That feels like failing.

Comment: I'm sure this question is more for exploration/learning, but to pragmatically solve this example I'd just live with the 1 line of duplicate code that is `fileprivate var uniqueKey: String? = NSUUID().uuidString` between 2 files.

Comment: I did in the end @Connor. It felt like I had failed and resorted to a not-best-practice solution. It still does. But...what to do exactly? I don't know.

Answer (score 2):

Here's something that gets pretty close to your ideal. The drawback is a runtime protocol cast in the extension method, but it accomplishes both the level of access control you are looking for (`fileprivate` stored var) and the code reuse via protocol extension:

```
fileprivate protocol UniqueKeyDefining {
    var uniqueKey: String? { get set }
}

class ClassA: ProtocolC, UniqueKeyDefining {
    fileprivate var uniqueKey: String?
}

class ClassB: ProtocolC, UniqueKeyDefining {
    fileprivate var uniqueKey: String?
}

protocol ProtocolC {
    func createKey()
}

extension ProtocolC {
    func createKey(){
        if var hasUniqueKey = self as? UniqueKeyDefining {
            hasUniqueKey.uniqueKey = NSUUID().uuidString
        } else {
            // Some default behavior if the conformer to ProtocolC isn't also UniqueKeyDefining
        }
    }
}
```

The protocol `UniqueKeyDefining` isn't visible outside of the file it was declared in, with `ClassA` and `ClassB`, so no code outside the file knows that those classes conform to it or have visibility into their `uniqueKey` ivars.

The specific protocol extension for `ProtocolC` is declared in the same file, so it *does* know about `UniqueKeyDefining` and can conditionally cast `self` to that protocol at runtime to get access to the `uniqueKey` ivar via that fileprivate protocol.

It doesn't seem to be very scalable or reusable with classes outside this file, but it meets the narrow set of requirements I interpreted from your question.

Comment: Nice @daniel-hall, I did not know that protocols could be fileprivate, that definitely helps.

Comment: why not do the last extension constrained? `extension ProtocolC where Self: UniqueKeyDefining`

Comment: @DeFrenZ - Because that extension would then not be visible outside the file (internally / publicly). I think the intent is to have `createKey()` defined and able to be called internally or publicly while making use of the fileprivate `uniqueKey` var of conforming classes

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to access something that is not defined in the protocol. Extensions are supposed to be based only on their public details. You're not supposed to access their privates.

I think what you actually want is "sharing implementation" rather than fighting with access control and type system. If you need to share implementation, just make an explicit implementation and share them.

```
protocol ProtocolC {
    func createKey()
}

class ClassA: ProtocolC {
    private var impl = Impl()
    func createKey() {
        impl.createKey()
    }
}

class ClassB: ProtocolC {
    private var impl = Impl()
    func createKey() {
        impl.createKey()
    }
}

private struct Impl {
    private(set) var uniqueKey: String? 
    mutating func createKey(){ 
        // Lock here.
        uniqueKey = NSUUID().uuidString
        // Unlock here.
    }
}
```

Avoiding dependency to private details is one of intention and design goal of `extension`s because such dependencies make code fragile, and such fragility is one of major problem of subclassing.

Comment: thanks @eonil. I know the question I'm asking is an impossibility. I just struggle with avoiding repeated code whilst using protocols/composition instead of inheritance. Your example is nice, but repeats code! Other than the letters A and B, both classes are identical! I'm imagining that in an "ideal world" I should only need to write the line `uniqueKey = NSUUID().uuidString` *once* somewhere *and nothing else*. But perhaps this just isn't possible

Comment: @TheMotherofJosephBeuys "A little copying is better than a little dependency." -- Rob Pike, https://go-proverbs.github.io

Comment: @TheMotherofJosephBeuys Also, the code `uniqueKey = NSUUID().uuidString` is actually shown only once in my example. It's up to you how to configure the other parts.

Comment: .@Eonil do you think none of either is better still? As in: getting punched in the arm is better than being punched in the face. Uh, how about just not getting punched, why isn't that an option?

Comment: @JosephBeuys'Mum I don't understand what you mean. What do you mean exactly?